# Undefined offset at PhpMatcherTrait

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

My project was working perfect. I wanted to write some new lines of code today but it gives me this error.

```
ErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: 6 
at vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherTrait.php:87
```

I have totally no idea what that is.

Checked what I was doing last when it was still working. I tried to configure authentication and registration form so according to tutorial I used these lines in terminal:

```
composer require symfony/security-csrf
composer require symfony/security-bundle
php bin/console make:user
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
composer update
```

Thats simply everything I did.

I am using Symfony 4.1 and PHP 7.1.3

This is a fresh project, with one view, one controller, it was working fine so far.

Will appreciate any help on this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that something has updated, - most likely Composer.

Try deleting your `vendor` folder and do a `composer install`.

Comment: Just did that right now. Unfortunately nothing changes. The same error even without `vendor` folder.

Comment: Hmm... In that case, then it must either be a faulty version of Symfony [not likely], - or something faulty that you pass to a function [much more likely :-) ]. So I think I would go to the very first file in the flow, and write: `<?php echo 'Hellow'; die(); ?>`, - to see if it makes it that far. If it does, then go to at 'later' file in the execution-line and do the same thing, and slowly try and isolate, where the problem occurs. You could also go through the error-stack and see if you can spot a file that you have editted. It could be a function expecting a string, getting an array, etc..

Comment: Wow I dont even know what to say. I did `die('hello');` before the view is rendered and it returned "hello". Then I deleted it, refreshed the website and it works 0_o?!

Comment: Okok - `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgraded php to 7.2 in the background lol. Maybe that was it

Comment: Ahh! Awesome. Then I'm pretty certain that deleting the `vendor`-folder actually worked, but that something was cached.

Comment: Fun fact: this problem actually comes from Symfony, not Composer. Also, Composer manages dependencies - it has nothing to do with your application, even less routing..
The order of the operations by the OP look wrong to me: instead, first do `composer update` and then rebuild your app (clear cache, migrate stuff etc)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after doing a `composer update`. Running `php bin/console cache:clear` in the terminal resolved it for me.